# iDisplayLenght and iDisplayStart not being posted to server side script for datatable

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, datatable

I am using datatables in a codeigniter 2.2 project which i have to add some new feautures. No data was being sent back in the json response. The query being executed was :

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS reference, narration, accountnumber, bank_name bank, amount FROM (`vb`) JOIN `bank_data` ON `bank_data`.`bank_code` =`vb`.`destinationcode` LIMIT 0
```

The issue is that the `limit` parameter has the value `0`

The following code snippet shows the code for getting limit values which i need for pagination because of my large dataset of over 22000 records:

```
  // Paging
        if(isset($iDisplayStart) && $iDisplayLength != '-1')
        {
            $this->db->limit($this->db->escape_str($iDisplayLength), $this->db->escape_str($iDisplayStart));
        }
```

The `$iDisplayStart` and `$iDisplayLength` parameters are gotten here

```
$iDisplayStart = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayStart', true);



$iDisplayLength =$this->input->get_post('iDisplayLength', true);
```

The challenge is that these values are not being posted to the server side script

My response JSON is :

```
{sEcho: 0, iTotalRecords: 23048, iTotalDisplayRecords: 0, iDisplayLength: false, iDisplayStart: false,…}
```

From the above, `iDisplayLength` and `iDisplayStart` are both false and therefore cause the limit value in the select statement to be `0`

My html to initialize the datatable is

```
$('#datatable_tabletools').dataTable({
        "bServerSide":true,
                "bProcessing": false,
                "sServerMethod": "POST",
                 "iDisplayLength": 25,
                 "iDisplayStart":0,

                  // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax":{'url':"<?php echo APP_URL.'/index.php/payments/getTable2';?>",
              'type':'POST',},
               "aoColumns": [

                        { "data": "reference" },
                        { "data": "narration" },
                        { "data": "accountnumber" },
                        { "data": "amount" },
                        { "data": "bank_name" }

                ],
```

The `$iDisplayStart` and `$iDisplayLength` parameters are set but not being posted, how can i rectify this? Thanks

Comment: If you using DataTables version 1.10, you are using deprecated stuff

Comment: IIRC, DataTables 1.10 is backwards-compatible with the old API if you use the `.dataTable()` method (instead of `.DataTable()`)

Answer (score -1):

```
{
render: function (data, type, row, meta) 
return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed answer and use `code` tag or external code editors to share examples.